# Using a negative stoptime for the fade argument in the SoX audio editor

Tags: audio, sox

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31277732/2166823) suggest that one can use a negative stoptime with `fade` to specify the time from the end of the file. Negative time specification works for me with `trim`, but not with `fade`.

This is what I have been trying

```
play audio-file trim 1:30 -1:20 fade t 20 -10 30
```

Which gives me the error

```
play FAIL fade: usage: [ type ] fade-in-length [ stop-time [ fade-out-length ] ]
   Time is in hh:mm:ss.frac format.
   Fade type one of q, h, t, l or p.
```

Changing the `-10` to `10` works just fine, so I wonder if it is at all possible to use negative stoptimes with fade or if that SO answer is mistaken. I am using SoX 14.4.1 on Raspbian with kernel 4.9.24-v7+.

Answer (score 0):

Your command line works fine for me using a 13-minute audio file and sox 14.4.2 from Debian stable on x86 CPU. No error message, it plays and is 2:50 shorter than the original.

You don't say the length of your audio file, but even if the result of the trim were shorter than 10 seconds, that still seems to work here.

Maybe they fixed some terrible bug between 14.4.1 and 14.4.2?

Maybe there's a signed-unsigned character bug in sox that only bites when the default char type is unsigned instead of signed (as it is on ARM if I remember correctly)? Can you try the same command with the same audio file on an x86 PC and see if you get the same failure?